# directions.getDuration() returns null

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to get duration and distance for a given directions via Google maps javascript v2 .What i am doing is on click of button i am sending ajax request which returns back with Latitude, Longitude information from server side(from a gpx file) den again i re-populate the div with map starting from new waypoint map                                    `

```
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var directionsPanel;

var directions;

var points_lt = [12.9172543,12.9326889,12.9761378,12.9896399];

var points_lg = [77.6230109,77.6131779,77.6017195,77.5928038];

function initialize() {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    var wp = new Array(2);
    wp[0] = new GLatLng(12.9172543,77.6230109);
    wp[1] = new GLatLng(13.0144572,77.5689697);
    map.setUIToDefault();

    // load directions
    directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
    directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
    directions.loadFromWaypoints(wp);

    }

function ChangeIt(){
    var cur_lt=null;
    var cur_lg=null;
    var cal=$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "./Handler.php?q=now",
      dataType: "html"
    }); 
    cal.done(function(msg){
       if(msg == 0){
        return false;
       }
       var Gpoint=msg.split("|");
       cur_lt=Gpoint[0];
       cur_lg=Gpoint[1];
       var wp = new Array(2);
       wp[0] = new GLatLng(cur_lt,cur_lg);
       wp[1] = new GLatLng(13.0144572,77.5689697);
       document.getElementById("map_canvas").innerHTML="";  
       map = null;
       directionsPanel.innerHTML = "" ;
       map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
       map.setUIToDefault();
       directions = new GDirections(map,directionsPanel);
       directions.loadFromWaypoints(wp);
       alert(directions.getDuration().html);
     });
}   
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a= function(){
            ChangeIt();
    };
    $("#bt1").click(function(){
        ChangeIt();
    });
    //setInterval(a, 3000); 

}); 
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <input type="button"  name="bt1" value="Change Route" id="bt1">
    &nbsp;<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px ;left:350px"></div>
<div id="route" style="width: 25%; height:480px; float:right; border; 1px solid black;">          </div>

<br/>
```

`

But when i try to getDistance or getDuration i get no alert.I think i is returning null or somthing which is not expected . please help  .I am new with google maps please let me know if i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please note that:

> The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially
>   deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until
>   May 19, 2013

I strongly recommend you migrate to Google API V3

Answer (score 0):

The Directions Service is asynchronous.  You can't access the results until the data comes back from the server.  See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services#ReturningDirections) for a description of the events that are available ("load" seems likely, but it has been a while since I looked at v2).

Note that the Google Maps API v2 is deprecated and really shouldn't be used for new development.

Comment: can you let me know how to do the same thing in V3

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for the directions class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) in v3?  It syntax is different, but there are lots of examples, I would suggest you give it a go and post your code if you can't get it to work.